# Spring Boot ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration instantiating two realms by default

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm debugging a spring boot application enabled with an actuator. I'm finding that the management application is instantiated under two different realms namely "Spring" and "Realm". (I'm not passing any realm name in the application.properties file.)

The "Spring" realm is being instantiated when the AuthenticationEntryPoint is configured on the below line of code (method - configure(HttpSecurity http))

```
            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint());
```

and subsequently in the same configure method the default realm is being initiated by the name "Realm" on the below line of code.

```
            http.httpBasic();
```

I think the above code is wrong/buggy.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Thanks!